# Passing OR in URL string

Tags: php

If there a way to use OR in a query statement?

What I am looking for is:

....?var1='ID'&var2='US'**OR**$var2='USA'**OR**$var2='United%20States'

Comment: What do you want this to do?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: and what should that mean? You can put anything in a parameter, you just have to make something out of it in your PHP script.

Answer (score 5):

Just do it in your php file.

Example :

```
$var2 = $_GET['var2'];
if($var2 == 'US' || $var2 == 'USA' || $var2 =='United States') {
    //Do your work here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If by "query statement" you mean the browser's query string, you can build an array with it, like so:

```
var2[]=US&var2[]=USA&var2=United%20States
```

The result will be an array `$_GET['var2']` with elements 'US', 'USA', and 'United States'.

In this sort of specific situation, though, it may make sense for your app to know synonyms on the server-side, instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it an array.

```
?var1=ID&var2[]=US&var2[]=USA&var2=United%20States
```

Then your `$_GET` will look like this:

```
array(2) {
  ["var1"]=>
  string(2) "ID"
  ["var2"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "US"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "USA"
    [2]=>
    string(13) "United States"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No.

Why don't you apply that logic in the script that handles the request?

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this:

```
?var1='ID'&var2='US'&var2='USA'&var2='United%20States'
```

which will result in :

```
$_GET = array(
   'var1' => 'ID',
   'var2' => 'United States'
);
```

So there is no **OR** per se, but the last value submitted wins.

Comment: well, he used `$`, not `&`, so var2 would be `'US'OR$var2='USA'OR$var2='United%20States'`